# Overloading = operator in c++

Tags: c++

I've just begun getting into classes in c++ and I was working on a class that defines 3D vectors. I was asked to overload the = operator and my professor suggested to implement it like this:

```
Vector3D& Vector3D::operator=(const Vector3D &rhs){
    vec[0] = rhs[0];
    vec[1] = rhs[1];
    vec[2] = rhs[2];
    return *this
}
```

I'm confused as to where the reference is returned and why do we use the "This" pointer. I asked my professor about this and he told me that it's necessary when we try to do succesive assignments like this:

```
Vector3D a;
Vector3D b;
Vector3D c=a=b;
```

Still, I don't understand why its necessary to have a return value as we have already updated the values before.

Comment: It's just a convention. You *can* write a `operator=` that returns `void` (according to the language standard), but it'll confuse people, because we all expect it to return a reference to the left-hand side. Also, not sure if you've figured this out yet, but just to save you the trouble, go read [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). You're implementing one of the three (five, if targeting C++11 or newer) operations, so you need to implement the other two (four).

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I think that over ten years should have been enough to assume C++11 unless specifically stated otherwise. Actually, I would assume C++17 by now, mimimum. We are not doing ourselves a favor using a >20 years old version of the language as baseline still.

Answer (score 2):

An assignment in C++ returns the object assigned to, and it is good practice to not change this kind of behavior when you are overloading an operator (*). This allows to e.g. check the value assigned, or assigning the same value to multiple objects.

Inside a member function, `this` is a pointer to the current object. So `*this` is the current (assigned-to) object, and the return type `Vector3D&` makes it clear that we are returning by reference, not by value.

---

(*) You cannot actually emulate the short-circuit evaluation of the `||` and `&&` operators, which is why you should not normally overload them.

Answer (score 2):

This (I know its slightly different, I wanted to make the chaining clear);

```
 Vector3D a;
 Vector3D b;
 Vector3D c;
 c=a=b; <<<<=====
```

is converted by the compiler to this:

```
 c.operator=(a.operator=(b));
```

This only works because `operator=` returns something that can be used as input to the next `operator=`.

You ask "why `return *this`;".

Well, the function has to return a reference to this invoked object, the only thing you have is `this`. You can't return that (excuse the pun) because its not a reference, it's a pointer, so you have to do `*this` to actually get the object it points to. The compiler sees you have declared the return type as `Vector3D&` so it knows to, in fact, return a reference, not the object itself.